# Google Drive & gapi: recent changes, no errors, no files returned

Tags: jquery, ajax, request, google-drive-api, google-api-js-client

For a couple of years now we've been using **gapi.client.request** to retrieve **files in folders from Google Drive**. The implementation was in v2, flowless.

A couple of days ago, the implementation returned an **empty array of files**.

We've decided to switch to v3.

The results are the same, namely no files retuned.

1. **Goodle Drive: folders & files** set to "Anyone on the Internet with this link can view"
2. **gapi client initialization**:

   ```
       gapi.load('client', function()
       {
           gapi.client.init({
                                   apiKey      : API_KEY,                                                                        
                                   scope       : ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file'],
                                   discoveryDocs: ["https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/drive/v3/rest"]
                               }).
                               then(function(resp)
                               {//Google Driver loaded 
                                  pCbkFunc(); 
                               });                
       });
   ```
3. **Request**

   ```
       gapi.client.request({
                               path    : "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?q='"+ID_FOLDER +"' in parents&orderBy=name",
                               corpa   : 'user',
                               params  : {'fields': "*"},
                               method  : 'GET'                                     
                           }).
       execute(function(pResp)
       {
           let arrayFiles = pResp.files;
        });
   ```
4. **Response**:

The Array Files above is an empty array.

5. **jQuery AJAX**

Obviously, we tried jQuery AJAX - the results are the same.

---

Does anybody else experience the same issues?
What is the solution?

As we are under lots of pressure, any help will be most appreciated
John

Comment: Sounds like this might be related to the [recent Drive security change](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/10729743?hl=en)

Comment: I have the same issue except I'm using a direct URL request to get the list of files in a folder.  The code was always using the v3 URL and hasn't changed in a long time and has worked fine.  Today I noticed a 200 response status but an empty "files" array in the returned JSON.  I even tried adding the resourcekey parameter for the folder to the request URL as suggested above regarding the new security changes, but still no luck.